# Backup status alert for Azure Database for MySQL - Single Server

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-mysql-database

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/concepts-backup#backups):
Azure Database for MySQL - Single Server takes backups of the data files and the transaction log.These backup files are not user-exposed and cannot be exported. These backups can only be used for restore operations in Azure Database for MySQL.

I want to create alert rules for those backups if anythings goes wrong. the only metrics i see in the logs is the used backup storage

```
AzureMetrics 
| where MetricName == "backup_storage_used"
```

Is there any solution to create the alert rules with the backup status?

Answer (score 1):

I get the backup failed alerts by using below process:

Firstly go to create an alert and then click on **select scope** then click on subscription, resource type and the resource group like below:

[image]

[image]

Then **select signal** then click on **Activity log** in signal type, Then select **Export an existing database**,

[image]

Then select `Failed` in status as below and then next :

[image]

Then select or create a action group:

[image]

Then next and fill details and then create like below:

[image]

This is the process I follow and I get alerts when the back up fails.

Comment: thank you for your help, the steps above are for SQL Databases but in my case i want to get alerts For MySQL.
In fact, i don't see the "export an existing database" signal.